# A working HDMI switch for Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, video

I have a Pi 3 and regular desktop computer with a single (DVI input) monitor. The desktop and Pi both have HDMI out for video. I use an HDMI > DVI cable to connect whichever device I want to use to the monitor.

Thought a [simple HDMI switch](https://smile.amazon.com/DotStone-Bi-Direction-Splitter-External-Required/dp/B01L8LLP2G) would be nice to save the hassle of switching the cable back-and-forth but it doesn't seem to work with the Pi. The message on the monitor says "Input not supported".

Is there some special consideration that needs to be given to the Pi3 when using an HDMI switch? From the reviews, it seems like a lot of people have this switch working between a TV and gaming console just fine.

/boot/config.txt

```
disable_overscan=1
overscan_left=0
overscan_right=0
overscan_top=0
overscan_bottom=0
hdmi_pixel_encoding=2
force_turbo=0
arm_freq=1200
core_freq=400
sdram_freq=450
over_voltage=0
gpu_mem=256
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_drive=2
start_x=0
max_usb_current=0
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
display_rotate=0
disable_audio_dither=1
[all]
[pi2]
max_usb_current=1
[all]
[all]
[pi3]
enable_uart=1
avoid_warnings=1
[all]
[all]
[EDID=ADA-HDMI]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28
display_rotate=2
[all]
[all]
[EDID=MST-HDMI1]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28
display_rotate=2
[all]
[all]
[EDID=MST-HDMI]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28
display_rotate=0
[all]
[all]
[EDID=HTC-HDMI]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28
display_rotate=0
[all]
[all]
[EDID=SAN-SANYO_LCD]
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4
[all]
[all]
[EDID=ACR-G236HL]
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28
```

Comment: perhaps you need to force the HDMI settings in `config.txt` in some way - see [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) - I would suggest `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=16` to start with ... pick a different mode if your monitor isn't 1080p of course

Comment: This is not a "simple" switch - it claims to be bi-directional. I use a hdmi switch, but you need to connect the Pi to the monitor BEFORE boot, OR set resolution and force HDMI output.

Comment: Thanks. I've added my `/boot/config.txt`. I have the Acer (ACR-G236HL) monitor hooked up to the HDMI switch which, I assume, means the pi is using the hdmi settings under that section. Does it use the same section when the switch is inline?

Comment: Unpowered splitters typically suck, passive switching is problematic with high speed signals . I  have had good luck with the 2:1 up to 6:1 active splitters even with the Shenzhen  specials on Amazon. Trying better cables may help with passive splitters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with this one. As long as I have the display active on the Pi when it's booting I can continue switching back-and-forth between it and my other system.

https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07L3SWJCQ/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1